# Extjs html editor and how to customize the editor

Tags: extjs

Hi i have been using Extjs html editor.I want to customize the html editor like i have to display a customized alert box when we click button in toolbar.how can we do that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is a bit vague.. Why kind of alert? What toolbar? What button? Any images of what you would like the alert to look like and when exactly would you like it to show up?

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.MyOwnHtmlEditor',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor',
    xtype: 'myhtmleditor',
    getToolbarCfg: function() {
        // get original toolbar:
        var toolbar = this.callParent(arguments);
        // add custom item:
        toolbar.items.push({
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-question-circle',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Dear user!', 'No, we won\'t help you!');
            }
        });
        // Modify handler of existing button:
        toolbar.items[3].handler = function() {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Dear user!', 'If you want Italic, please go to Italy!');
        };
        // return toolbar to calling function
        return toolbar;
    }
})
```

And use it e.g. like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'myhtmleditor'
}
```

[Example fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23qv)